# Proving every inverse is in Aut($\mathbb{Z}_n$).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\pi_i: \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$ be a homomorphism defined by $\pi_i(g)=ig \;$.

Let Aut($\mathbb{Z}_n$) be the set of automorphisms on $\mathbb{Z}_n \;$. Then if $\pi_i \in$ Aut($\mathbb{Z}_n$), gcd$(i, n) = 1 \;$.

If I understand correctly, to prove an element, say $\pi_a \in$ Aut($\mathbb{Z}_n$), has an inverse, I simply need to prove there is another element $\pi_m \in$ Aut($\mathbb{Z}_n$) such that $ma\equiv 1$ mod $n \;$, and we can use Bezout's identity to help find such an $m$. We can then use this $m$ to satisfy an equivalence $m\equiv l$ mod $n$ where $l \in \mathbb{Z}_n$.

My question is: how do we know gcd($l, n) = 1 \;$, so that we know $\pi_l \in$ Aut($\mathbb{Z}_n$) too?

Answer (score 1):

The way you stated the problem: *If $\pi_i\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ then $\gcd(i,n)=1$.*

**One confusion** You say: "If I understand correctly, to prove an element, say $\pi_a \in$ Aut($\mathbb{Z}_n$), has an inverse, I simply need to prove there is another element $\pi_m \in$ Aut($\mathbb{Z}_n$) such that $ma\equiv 1$ mod $n$." But the problem you are given is not about proving $\pi_a\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$, on the contrary, that is your hypothesis! You seem to be trying to prove the converse statement.

I suggest you prove the negation: *If $\gcd(i,n)=d\neq 1$ then $\pi_i$ is not injective*.

That being said, the converse statement: *If $\gcd(i,n)=1$ then $\pi_i\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$* is also true. And your idea of finding $j$ such that $ij\equiv1\mod{n}$ is also completely on point. However, I suggest you take a slightly different approach to finding $j$:

**Hint**: If $\gcd(i,n)=1$, then prove that there exists $1<k<n$ such that $i^k=1\mod n$. Use this to construct your $j$.

The converse statement can also be proven more directly and simply by just showing if $\pi_i$ is injective if $\gcd(i,n)=1$.

Comment: I think part of my confusion lies in that I don't know if gcd$(a, n) = 1$ and gcd$(ab, n) = 1$ implies gcd$(b, n) = 1$ or not. Also, if so, I'm not really sure how to prove this specifically if this is the case.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need this, but this statement is true and you can prove it by nothing that if b and n have a common divisor, then the same number divides both ab and n.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't see that. I guess I think I need it because then I say we have an inverse in the form of $\pi_z$ where $z = b$ mod $n$, thus any arbitrary element in the set of autmorphisms has an inverse.

Comment: Also, would this work toward proving gcd$(b, n) = 1$: $a\equiv1$ mod $n$ and $ab \equiv 1$ mod $n$ $\implies$ $ab-a \equiv 0$ mod $n$ $\implies$ $a(b-1) \equiv 0$ mod $n$ $\implies$ $r-1 \equiv 0$ mod $n$ $\implies$ $r \equiv 1$ mod $n$ ?

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment as we don't know that $a \equiv 1$ mod $n$.